# How does the so-called skeleton key (master password) in Mimikatz work?

Tags: windows, mimikatz

I've used Mimikatz to patch the domain controller with a skeleton key `misc::skeleton`, which makes it possible for any domain user to authenticate with the password "mimikatz", while still being able to use their original password.

However, what is it that allows this to happen on the domain controller? In other words, how can a username be associated to multiple passwords?

Off-topic: Is it possible to change the master password ("mimikatz") to something else on the mimikatz command-line?

Comment: According to the link provided at the end of this comment, it appears to "patch" the active directory controller to enable this. https://adsecurity.org/?p=1255

Comment: @xorist - Yes, but what exactly does this mean? I've tried to read the source code, but it is hard to read :/